# How to turn objects in an array with the same keys into a seperate object of their own in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects with the same keys, I want to create a new array of objects that creates a new object that combines the uniques ones together into one

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
{ 'Serial Number': '90946117350061093222581604839920' },
{ 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891733' },
{ 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891734' },
{ 'Part Number': 'TR40-60C779-AA' },
{ 'Part Number': 'ST41-60C780-AA' },
{ 'Part Number': 'QT41-60C780-AA' },
{ 'Cell Count': '28' },
{ 'Cell Count': '27' },
{ 'Cell Count': '29' },
{ 'Length': '10' },
{ 'Length': '11' },
{ 'Length': '11' },
]
```

So it needs to look like the below.

```
const desiredArrayOfObjects = [
{ 
    'Serial Number': '90946117350061093222581604839920',
    'Part Number': 'TR40-60C779-AA',
    'Cell Count': '27',
    'Length': '10',
},
{ 
    'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891733',
    'Part Number': 'ST41-60C780-AA',
    'Cell Count': '28',
    'Length': '11',
},
{ 
    'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891734',
    'Part Number': 'QT41-60C780-AA',
    'Cell Count': '29',
    'Length': '12',
},

]
```

I have tried it with the code below, but i'm clearly not getting it right, help is welcome and appreciated.

```
let newArr = [];
arrayOfObjects.map((x,i) => {
    Object.entries(x).map(([key, value]) => {
        if(!newArr.length){
            
            if(Object.keys(newArr[i]).toString() === key){
                newArr.push({[key]: value})                   
            }

        }
    })
})
```

Comment: From my point of view, it's impossible to build up the `desiredArrayOfObjects` from `arrayOfObjects` because there is not any relationship among the objects in `arrayOfObjects`. I mean, I cannot see how to interrelate these objects.

Comment: @Ele I think it's based on the order. First Serial Number, first Part Number, first Cell Count, and first Length all go together.

Comment: `if(!newArr.length){if(Object.keys(newArr[i]).toString() === key){` `newArr` doesn't have any entries, so how would you expect to set `newArr[i]` to a string?

Comment: @user1599011 no, that's not true. See the `Length` `=` `12`

Comment: @Ele, how, when we just checked `if(!newArr.length){`?    This is not the key `Length`, it's an array length.

Comment: @user1599011 I'm talking about the `desiredArrayOfObjects` array (output).

Comment: @ele, I see. I think that's probably a typo. But definitely makes it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'best if you first separate them and the put it back together

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
{ 'Serial Number': '90946117350061093222581604839920' },
{ 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891733' },
{ 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891734' },
{ 'Part Number': 'TR40-60C779-AA' },
{ 'Part Number': 'ST41-60C780-AA' },
{ 'Part Number': 'QT41-60C780-AA' },
{ 'Cell Count': '28' },
{ 'Cell Count': '27' },
{ 'Cell Count': '29' },
{ 'Length': '10' },
{ 'Length': '11' },
{ 'Length': '11' },
]

const keys = ['Serial Number', 'Part Number', 'Cell Count', 'Length']

const separated = arrayOfObjects.reduce((res, item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0]
  const existing = res[key] || []
  res[key] = [...existing, item[key]]
  return res
}, {})

const result = separated[keys[0]].map((_, i) => {
  return keys.reduce((res, k ) => {
    return {...res, [k]: separated[k][i]}
  }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't require knowing the properties ahead of time would be to separate the array into sub-arrays of matching property, and then map over the longest of these sub-arrays merging the contained objects into one. (This does require that all like properties be sequential in the source array.)

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{ 'Serial Number': '90946117350061093222581604839920' }, { 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891733' }, { 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891734' }, { 'Part Number': 'TR40-60C779-AA' }, { 'Part Number': 'ST41-60C780-AA' }, { 'Part Number': 'QT41-60C780-AA' }, { 'Cell Count': '28' }, { 'Cell Count': '27' }, { 'Cell Count': '29' }, { 'Length': '10' }, { 'Length': '11' }, { 'Length': '11' },];

const grouped = [];
let prev;
for (const obj of arrayOfObjects) {
  const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
  if (key !== prev) {
    grouped.push([]);
  }
  grouped.at(-1).push(obj);
  prev = key;
}

const result = grouped
  .sort(({ length: a }, { length: b }) => b - a)[0]
  .map((_, i) => Object.assign(...grouped.map(p => p[i] ?? {})));

console.log(result)
```

Or, using grouping if the order of the source array is unknown (the object the individual properties end up in will still be sensitive to the ordering of the source array)

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{ 'Serial Number': '90946117350061093222581604839920' }, { 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891733' }, { 'Serial Number': '77362117350061093222581604891734' }, { 'Part Number': 'TR40-60C779-AA' }, { 'Part Number': 'ST41-60C780-AA' }, { 'Part Number': 'QT41-60C780-AA' }, { 'Cell Count': '28' }, { 'Cell Count': '27' }, { 'Cell Count': '29' }, { 'Length': '10' }, { 'Length': '11' }, { 'Length': '11' },];

const grouped = {}
for (const obj of arrayOfObjects) {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(obj);
  (grouped[key] ??= []).push(value);
}

const result = [];
for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(grouped)) {
  for (const [i, value] of values.entries()) {
    (result[i] ??= {})[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can you please explain the variable name "chunked"? The technical jargon/reasoning

Comment: chunking is usually done by count ie to split a 1d array into a 2d array of equally sized sub-arrays [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks), so it's not totally accurate to this use case. Should probably be 'grouped' which is a little more descriptive.